# Comprehensive mime type detection by looking at data?

Tags: node.js

Is there a node lib that determines the mime type of a file other than [mmmagic](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic)? That one detects DOCX as `application/zip` and JSON as `text/plain`.

[mime-types](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-types), OTOH, is easily fooled by changing the file extension.

Is there a modern version of libmime that supports recent file types, and perhaps falls back to file extension sniffing via [mime-db](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db) if it can't be determined?

Comment: Incidentally, docx _is_ a zip file, so you'll need that "file extension sniffing" to detect that it isn't just any old zip file. Same for the other Office *.___x files.

Comment: @sfuqua Right, so I'd need something that does both. data-sniffing to determine it's actually a zip, and extension checking to determine what kind of zip.